# Locally compact cut-point space must be $\mathbb R$?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $X$ is a connected separable metric space, and $X\setminus \{x\}$ has exactly two connected components for every $x\in X$.

If $X$ is **locally connected**, then $X\simeq \mathbb R$.  This was noted in previous answers to

https://mathoverflow.net/a/319872/95718

and

https://mathoverflow.net/a/76139/95718.

My questions is, is the conclusion the same ($X$ homeomorphic to the reals $\mathbb R$) if $X$ is **locally compact**?

Answer (score 0):

$X=\{(x, \sin(\frac{1}{x}): x >0\} \cup \{0\} \times \Bbb R$ looks like a potential counterexample.

**edit** Removing the non-cutpoints so

$X=\{(x, \sin(\frac{1}{x}): x >0\} \cup \left(\{0\} \times (\Bbb R \setminus (-1,1))\right)$ seems to work better (thanks to [David Hartley](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/169394/david-hartley)'s comment).

Comment: No, points in $\{0\} \times (-1,1)$ aren't cut points.

Comment: @DavidHartley. Agreed.............

Comment: @DavidHartley And if we remove that segment from $X$? Or do we lose local compactness at $(0,1)$ and $(0,-1)$?

Comment: Your comment is correct, you lose local compactness when you remove that segment.

Comment: @DavidHartley Can you explain why?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma No neighborhood $N$ of $(0,1)$ in the new $X$ is compact. The closure of $N$ always contains points of $\{ 0 \} \times (-1,1)$.